# Unpack list of objects into separate attributes

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I have a simple Python class like this:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I create a list of these objects e.g.:

```
import random

list_of_objects = [P(random.random(), random.random()) for i in range(1000)]
```

How do I then unpack the attributes of P into different lists?

That is, my goal is to obtain `list_of_x, list_of_y`, where these are defined as:

```
list_of_x = [p.x for p in list_of_objects]
list_of_y = [p.y for p in list_of_objects]
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way e.g. using zip/tuples, rather than the code above, which involves 2 for-loops.

Comment: Looks clean and fast to me. Likely faster than Terry's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is always several ways to write something in a one-liner in Python, but I would not recommend it at all:

```
list_of_x, list_of_y = map(list, zip(*[p.__dict__.values() for p in list_of_objects]))
```

or more explicit:

```
list_of_x, list_of_y = map(list, zip(*[(p.x, p.y) for p in list_of_objects]))
```

Yet what you are doing is both clear and efficient, so I see no reason to write it in a one-liner. The above-mentioned implementations are not efficient since it involves additional copies to convert the list of pairs in two independent tuples, then to convert tuples in lists.

Comment: This still ends up doing 2 iterations(1 for the list comp, 1 for zip/unpack) and you end up with tuples, not lists.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was about using a single for-loop. Fixed tuple type issue using infamous `map`.

Comment: Bit shorter way to convert to lists, rather for fun: `[*list_of_x], [*list_of_y] = zip(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 1 for loop and append the x/y to empty lists:

```
list_of_x = []
list_of_y = []
for p in list_of_objects:
    list_of_x.append(p.x)
    list_of_y.append(p.y)
```

Comment: Not sure that's good advice, given how it spreads creation over multiple separate statements (so I wouldn't call it "cleaner") and appears to take about [twice as much time](https://tio.run/##fVHLbsMgELzzFXsECVmJcqkq5R9y6C2KELEh3co8hIlkvt4FY9dKmnYviJllZjT4FD@dPbz5ME06OAMRjcIIaLwLEYLySkay3qTtnCGk7eUwwIm665dqI3snkKdTGoRAi1EIOqhecxg5pIUtU8BmhCOMj1DKUCKkxyEKp0VVHTJ4PtFq2dSDMg5PAAPtAiCgLcxN0f1ut2MXQkocF/CGVvZ0CbE6lAxnn6OUt768ffK@PKynup7@WZ/tPlQI6aXXC70K/aW4lfaj00jvle1ozs1@sWljEyOkyIqtk8OSqcD6btvCrN3wGnszjDmdQUvr19Oyz8HezVWF41zu5u4D2kgjn0UbIaw0SojKV46RafoG).